# Узнать цвет фона изображения

Tags: php, изображения

Как возможно узнать цвет картинки, точнее фон этой картинки или просто какой цвет находится по краям?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290259/detect-main-colors-in-an-image-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам понадобниться библиотека которая умеет это делать(gd, imagemagic ...)
http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php
http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

**GD**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php

```
<?php
    $path = realpath('../path/to/./your/folder/testimage.jpg');
    if ($path) {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($path);
        $rgb = imagecolorat($im, 10, 15);

        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
        var_dump($r, $g, $b);

        $colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);
        var_dump($colors); // rgba
    } else {
       echo "Invalid file path";
    }
```

**ImageMagick**

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagepixelcolor.php

```
<?php 

    $path = realpath('../path/to/./your/folder/testimage.jpg');
    if ($path) {
        $image = new Imagick($path); 

        $x = 1; 
        $y = 1; 
        $pixel = $image->getImagePixelColor($x, $y); 

        $colors = $pixel->getColor(); 
        var_dump($colors); // produces Array([r]=>255,[g]=>255,[b]=>255,[a]=>1); 

        var_dump($pixel->getColorAsString()); // produces rgb(255,255,255);
    } else {
       echo "Invalid file path";
    }
```

Только протестировал.

1) Нужен полный путь к файлу. Относительные не работали правильно. http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php. `realpath` вернет `false` если путь неправильный.

2) GD для работу с прозрачностью надо использовать. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorsforindex.php (только там прозрачность по другому считает 0 - непрозрачный 127 - прозрачный)

Обновил код.

Comment: Первый выдает ответ: int(0) int(0) int(0)
Второй не даёт ответа вообще.

Comment: @СашаОсипов у вас точно оба раширения установлены?

Comment: Да, подключены. Причина в том, что файл с криптом должен находиться в одной папке с изображением... Как исправить? Потому-что все изображения храняться в отдельной папке. Расширение указано правильно.

Comment: @СашаОсипов Обновил код/ответ.

Comment: Сам нашел проблему, очень интересная конечно...
http://prntscr.com/dx3q50 - страница
http://prntscr.com/dx3qau - скрипт
Причина: В php надо ставить другое расширение....

Answer (score 0):

Сделать принт скрин и открыть в фотошопе посмотреть инструментом пипетка - кнопка i на клавиатура, если нет фотошопа, то в пейнте. Если не хочется таким образом. Есть [плагин](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorpick-eyedropper/ohcpnigalekghcmgcdcenkpelffpdolg) - в браузере хром он показывает цвета.

Comment: Вы совсем не поняли... Надо узнать RGB изображения средствами php